# Rules not working with multiple OR condition

Tags: rules, users

I am using rules & profile2 module.There are profile types like personal information, contact deatails. Now,I want to send email notification to user to fill out empty profile fields. If any one of the profile field is empty,user should receive a mail regarding profile completion. For this, i have created a rule where i  tried "Data value is empty" with multiple OR condition for muliple profile fields in rules condition.But the rule with multiple OR condition is not working.Is it possible with rules or is there any php coding to do this? Since I am new to drupal,not getting how to do this.Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: what event does it react on? are you sure the Rule is running at all?

Comment: It's acting on the event "user has logged in" & yes the rule is running but the Multiple OR condition is not working to check out the empty profile fields.